# cmake fails to find this package

Tags: cmake

I am in the process of compiling some robotics software examples. The CMakelist should download this package `cppzmq` from github as shown below

```
FetchContent_Declare(cppzmq
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cppzmq
)
```

When I build the examples, I get this warning

```
CMake Warning at build/cppzmq/examples/CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcppzmq.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "cppzmq", but
  CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cppzmq" with any
  of the following names:

    cppzmqConfig.cmake
    cppzmq-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "cppzmq" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "cppzmq_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "cppzmq"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

It appears that the package has been downloaded to the build folder. However, there are no compilation errors. Is this warning a cause for concern? The CMakelists file is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(zmqRemoteApi-client-cpp3)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

if(NOT LIBPLUGIN_DIR)
    if(DEFINED ENV{COPPELIASIM_ROOT_DIR})
        set(LIBPLUGIN_DIR $ENV{COPPELIASIM_ROOT_DIR}/programming/libPlugin)
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Environment variable COPPELIASIM_ROOT_DIR is not set")
    endif()
endif()
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules
    ${LIBPLUGIN_DIR}/cmake)
find_package(CoppeliaSim 4.1.0.0 REQUIRED)
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter)

option(GENERATE "Generate wrappers for objects and methods (requires CoppeliaSim to be running)")

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(jsoncons
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/jsoncons
)
FetchContent_GetProperties(jsoncons)
if(NOT jsoncons_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(jsoncons)
    #add_subdirectory(${jsoncons_SOURCE_DIR} ${jsoncons_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()

FetchContent_Declare(cppzmq
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cppzmq
)
FetchContent_GetProperties(cppzmq)
if(NOT cppzmq_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(cppzmq)
    add_subdirectory(${cppzmq_SOURCE_DIR} ${cppzmq_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/calltips.json"
    COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env
        PYTHONPATH="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../python"
        ${Python3_EXECUTABLE}
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../tools/get_raw_calltips.py"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/calltips.json"
    DEPENDS
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../tools/get_raw_calltips.py"
)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/constants.json"
    COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env
        PYTHONPATH="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../python"
        ${Python3_EXECUTABLE}
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../tools/get_constants.py"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/constants.json"
    DEPENDS
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../tools/get_constants.py"
)

set(generatedFiles)
file(GLOB templateFiles RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/templates/ ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/templates/*)
foreach(templateFile ${templateFiles})
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/${templateFile}"
        COMMAND
            ${Python3_EXECUTABLE}
            "${LIBPLUGIN_DIR}/simStubsGen/external/pycpp/pycpp.py"
            -p "calltips_json=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/calltips.json"
            -p "constants_json=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/constants.json"
            -i "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/templates/${templateFile}"
            -o "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/${templateFile}"
            -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../tools"
            -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
        DEPENDS
            "${LIBPLUGIN_DIR}/simStubsGen/external/pycpp/pycpp.py"
            "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/templates/${templateFile}"
            "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/calltips.json"
            "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/constants.json"
            "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp_utils.py"
            "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../tools/calltip.py"
            "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../tools/calltip.lark"
    )
    list(APPEND generatedFiles "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/${templateFile}")
endforeach()
add_custom_target(generate_code DEPENDS ${generatedFiles})

add_library(RemoteAPIClient STATIC RemoteAPIClient.cpp)
if(GENERATE)
    add_dependencies(RemoteAPIClient generate_code)
else()
    foreach(templateFile ${templateFiles})
        if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${templateFile}")
            message(FATAL_ERROR "File ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${templateFile} is missing")
        endif()
    endforeach()
endif()
target_compile_definitions(RemoteAPIClient PUBLIC -DSIM_REMOTEAPICLIENT_OBJECTS)
target_include_directories(RemoteAPIClient PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/jsoncons/include)
target_include_directories(RemoteAPIClient BEFORE PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated)
target_link_libraries(RemoteAPIClient PUBLIC cppzmq)

add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE RemoteAPIClient)

add_executable(synchronousImageTransmission synchronousImageTransmission.cpp)
target_link_libraries(synchronousImageTransmission PRIVATE RemoteAPIClient)

add_executable(bubbleRobClient bubbleRobClient.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bubbleRobClient PRIVATE RemoteAPIClient)

find_package(OpenCV COMPONENTS core imgproc highgui)
if(OpenCV_FOUND)
    add_executable(opencv opencv.cpp)
    target_include_directories(opencv PRIVATE ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(opencv PRIVATE RemoteAPIClient)
    target_link_libraries(opencv PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
endif()

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets Gui)
if(Qt5_FOUND)
    add_executable(qt qt.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(qt PRIVATE RemoteAPIClient)
    target_link_libraries(qt PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets)
endif()
```

I'm using cmake `3.25.2`. Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but does adding OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE to the FetchContent_Declare(cppzmq... fix the problem?

Comment: @RobertPrévost would you please elaborate a bit more? How should I put that line?

Comment: It is an option on FetchContent_Declare (see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html)).

Comment: `When I build the examples` How do you build them? Code works fine for me.  Do we need all this code to reproduce? Please remove all the lines until you are left with MCVE. So why do you build tests? Why not just not build them? Have you read `build/cppzmq/examples/CMakeLists.txt` and `build/cppzmq/CMakeLists.txt` to try to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soooo do not include and build cppzmq tests and examples. See  https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/master/examples/CMakeLists.txt#L13 and https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L104 .

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(zmqRemoteApi-client-cpp3)
include(FetchContent)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv this is the important part
set(CPPZMQ_BUILD_TESTS OFF)
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FetchContent_Declare(cppzmq
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cppzmq
)
FetchContent_GetProperties(cppzmq)
if(NOT cppzmq_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(cppzmq)
    add_subdirectory(${cppzmq_SOURCE_DIR} ${cppzmq_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()
```

Comment: The instructions I'm following say 
`Any C++ client requires the jsoncons and cppzmq package: those are automatically downloaded and used when compiling via cmake. For details see programming/zmqRemoteApi/clients/cpp/, which contains several examples.`
The actual commands are 
`$mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -DGENERATE=OFF ..
$ cmake --build . --config Release`

Comment: Then add `-DCPPZMQ_BUILD_TESTS=OFF`

Comment: This indicates sloppy instructions, right?

Comment: `-DCPPZMQ_BUILD_TESTS=OFF` did resolve the issue. Thank you!